# C++ OpenGL colour array in a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers, opengl

I am trying to loop through a draw function in OpenGL and select a different colour array depending on the number in the for loop, to colour two sets of triangles (0 = white, 1 = black for example).

This is what I have

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0, myShapeArray); //load shape array
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, myColorArray ); //load colour array
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(differentArray[i]->xPos,differentArray[i]->yPos,-10.0f); // move on x/y/z
        glRotatef(differentArray[i]->rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); //rotate on z
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);   //draw triangles
}
```

Currently, it loads two sets of triangles (as a square) then sets both sets of triangles the same colour, I want the squares to different colours.

I've tried a few different things, I have tried moving colour array down to just above the draw, then pushing before the array, poping after drawing, then load the other array but this still sets them both the same.

The only other option I thought was having an array that holds the memory locations of the different arrays so if i=0, it will load one array, if i=1, it loads the other.

I have spent a while playing around with this and getting no closer, any advice would be appreciated... thanks in advance.

Comment: The most straighforward way would be to stop using fixed pipeline and rewriting the whole thing using shaders. Then you can pass the grid data any way you like, as an uniform, as a texture, whatever.

Comment: You think that would be the best way? Hmm, this is part of my University coursework, we were given the template and told to make a simple 2D game from that.. I've not had any experience with OpenGL other than writing bits for this coursework but will look into rewriting it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want two color arrays if you want two colors. Use myColorArray  when i==0 and myOtherColorArray when i==1. But first you have to initialize it. Simply copy paste myColorArray and rename.

Comment: Wow, that was a lots easier than I was expecting! I keep getting told by my lecturers I always try to make it more complicated than it needs to be, case and point.. Thank you!!!